# Jquery Fadein() effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know how to write code for jquery fadein effect.
suppose i have a html element store in variable.
like

```
var sHtml="<div>Other content</<div><div id='frm'>hello</<div>"
 modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm')fadein().html());
```

i first find the desired div and use the fadein effect when i am assigning the div inside modal box. but it is not working. cany anyone suggest me to do it proper way. i want that when i will set the content into modal box then first i will show a fadein effect and then set the content.

### Here i am giving my code

```
 var modal = "";
    var sHtml = "";

    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#btnFeedback1").click(function () {
            var modal = new LightFace({
                draggable: true,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                title: 'Login',
                content: '<div class="BusyStyles"><div>',
                buttons: [
                { title: 'OK', event: function () {
                    if (Validate()) {
                        if (Save()) {
                            this.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                },
                { title: 'Close', event: function () { this.close(); } }
            ]
            }).open();

            //}).open();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Login_LightFace.aspx/GetHtml",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    sHtml = data.d;
                    //modal.options.width = 'auto';
                    //modal.options.height = 'auto';
                    modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm').fadeIn().html());
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Questions are easier to read when you perform the requisite capitalisation of letters at the start of sentences.

Comment: @thomas: please show your markup and script. would like to see your code.

Comment: You have `</<div>` and `')fadein` which are not correct.

Comment: i have update my question with full code please see it. i am using LightFace plugin for modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what is that modal.load but when you are adding new thing to somewhere and want to have fadeIn type of effect, you should first just hide the element you just added (or have style="display:hidden") and then use fadeIn on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such effect in jquery as `fadein` but there is `fadeIn` (capital I).  Also you missed a dot before fadeIn()

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler like this:

```
modal.load(function() { ...event handling code here...; });
```

If you don't wrap it in a `function(){}` it will run immediately instead of when the event fires.